# Vim Plugin haskellConceal Not Concealing

Tags: haskell, vim

I've loaded the haskellConceal plugin for Vim (using pathogen). It doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I am missing something.

- I'm running Windows 8.1 and Vim 7.4.
- The file is located at bundle/haskellConceal/after/syntax/haskell.vim.
- I've got the line `call pathogen#infect()` in my _vimrc.
- I've got the line `-- vim: fenc=utf-8` in my source file.
- I `:set enc=utf-8`.
- I open a `.hs` file. Nothing. No concealment of specified character sequences.

When I `:set cole`, usually it returns `conceallevel=0`, which to me would indicate that the file is not being sourced. I just `:set cole`d again, and it responded with `conceallevel=2`. But still, no concealment.

I noticed the haskellConceal script considers three fonts incomplete: `Consolas`, `Lucida Console`, and `Courier New`. I'm using `APL385 Unicode`.

Am I understanding the `conceal` feature correctly? Shouldn't `->` be replaced in my source code with the Unicode character when I open the file, or when I type it and move to another line? I'm missing something, or misunderstanding, I guess. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why not open an issue in plugin's issue tracker?

Comment: It unconceals the characters when you're on another line. In any case, this is probably the wrong place to look for help regarding that.

Comment: I've submitted an issue. I'll post the response here when I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I had installed the plugin in `$VIMRUNTIME` instead of `$HOME/vimfiles`. I moved my `bundle` folder to `$HOME/vimfiles/`, and it worked!